# MS Sql server Hostname connectivity issue

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, hostname

We are facing connectivity issue with MSSQL server using an Java application.
My Hostname for the Mssql server is the below

```
 “chennai.sqlsrv.codings.group.vps.local\cpss3"
```

Is there any limitation for the host name character ?..or such below reasons

1. String too long ?
2. String malformed (\cpss3) ?

In other words if we open a connection using SqlServer Management Studio and we use the same parameters then we’re able to see and browse DB’s objects.

If i use the Hostname as "CPP123" then my Java application works fine without any connectivity issue.

Any help will be much appreciated..

Comment: double backslash?  quotename? "[chennai.sqlsrv.codings.group.vps.local\cpss]" ?

Comment: Hi Mitch.. Thanks for a swift response..Its a single backslash... No   quotename

Comment: I;m suggesting you might need to do those things....

Comment: You are suggesting to try the Hostname as "chennai.sqlsrv.codings.group.vps.local\\cpss" in my Java application